# 3Com 5500G EI Switch Stack Configuration

Tags: switch, stacking, 3-com

I have 2 3Com 5500 switch in stack and one of them is fault, I want to replace them with a new switch, which configuration must be added to the new switch before it can be added to the switch stack? (It's like a Cisco, no configuration is required?)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends which one is the "management device".  [Switch 5500 Family Configuration Guide](http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c02581968-1.pdf).

[image]

[image]